# Apollo Client Cache - how to merge items within a Modifier

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I want to modify my Apollo cache with a `Modifier` which merges old and new data like:

```js
const myModifier: Modifier<Reference> = (prevData, details) => {
   return {
      ...prevData,
      someField: 'updatedValue'
   }
}
```

But I'm not sure how reliable my approach is. According to the [documenation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#values-vs-references) `prevData` is a `Reference` since it's an object. So, will `someField` get updated or just get dropped?
How can I create a proper, updated return value? I tried to get the item with like `details.readField(details.storeFieldName)`, but this returns `undefined`.

The [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify) isn't really helpful when it comes to explaining what I've got to return in a `Modifier`, or how to use `readField` in this context.

Comment: congrats! you finally just got found the perfect time for using immerjs! https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer

Comment: I don't think so. the problem is that I don't have a real previous state but probably just a reference I can't resolve, and this won't change with immer.